# Get custom user field meta data in woocommerce_ajax_get_customer_details when adding new order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added a custom field to the billing details section in the user profile. It functions correctly on the frontend but not in the admin panel. When I manually create orders through the admin panel and select a user in the new order tab, all their basic details from their account are retrieved properly except for my custom field. Could you please help me?

Here is my current code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_get_customer_details' , 'add_custom_fields_to_ajax_customer_details', 10, 3 );
function add_custom_fields_to_ajax_customer_details( $data, $customer, $user_id ) {

    // Pętla przez pola ustawień

    // Pobierz i dodaj NIP
    $data['billing']['billing_nip'] = $customer->get_meta('billing_nip');

    return $data;
}
```

Field ID is billing_nip

I have tried to write my own code but it doesn't work.